Null space of linear transformation
We are given a linear transformation $\Phi:C[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ such that $$\Phi(f(x))=\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm dx$$ where $C[0,1]$ is the set of all continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R.$ We have to find the null space of $\Phi$.
My Approach
$$\operatorname{null}{(\Phi})=\left\{f:\Phi(f)=0\right\}=\left\{f:\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm dx=0\right\}$$ That is, $\operatorname{null}(\Phi)$ is the set of those continuous functions in $C[0,1]$ whose definite integral from $0$ to $1$ equals $0$. Some of those functions should be symmetric about the point $\left(\frac12,0\right)$ i.e satisfy the property $$f(x)+f(1-x)=0 ,\forall x\in[0,1]$$ But there are many other functions left. How to get idea about them? What is the approach? Is there any other way of describing all such functions of $\Phi$?

You can't expect to get a better answer than$$\ker\Phi=\left{f\in C[0,1],\middle|,\int_0^1f(x),\mathrm dx=0\right}.$$

The closest decription you can give is (I think): Given any function $f \in C[0,1]$, the function $f-\int_0^1 f dx$ is definitely in $\ker \Phi$.

It is almost be definition the zero average functions.

What is $\ker \Phi$? I have not yet reached the topic of kernel.

The kernel of the linear transformation $\Phi: C[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\Phi(f) = \int_0^1 f(x) , dx$ consists of all continuous functions $f$ on the interval $[0,1]$ for which the output of $\Phi$ is zero.

@user1397406 So $\ker\Phi$ is nothing but null space of $\Phi$. Thanks!

@Engineer Yes. Typically, the term null space is reserved for matrices whereas "kernel" is used for linear operators. Of course, this is not a universal convention
